# Rspec run all tests except a specific folder

Tags: ruby, rspec

The project I'm working on has a fairly large test suite. I am currently writing test that passes when I run it alone but when I run the entire test suite `$rspec` I get some really funky behavior that causes the test to fail.

Right now the test is nested like this:

```
spec/folder1/folder2/folder3/test.rb
```

Each of these commands run the test fine and everything passes:

```
$rspec spec/folder1/folder2/folder3
$rspec spec/folder1/folder2
$rspec spec/folder1/
```

There are about 10 other folders at the same level as `folder1` that I would like to individually not run with the rest of the suite in order to determine which folder contains tests that are breaking the test I am working on.

Is this possible?

Comment: Use an `--exclude-pattern`: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-3/docs/configuration/exclude-pattern

Comment: @photoionized this worked perfect. Care to post an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: sure, thing, just posted :)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use an `--exclude-pattern`, they're quite convenient:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-3/docs/configuration/exclude-pattern

One of the nice things about them:

> The `--exclude-pattern` flag accepts shell style glob unions

So you could do something like `rspec --exclude-pattern "spec/{foldername1,foldername2}/**/*_spec.rb"`

Comment: FYI, you can also exclude multiple directories (or patterns) by separating them by commas, `"spec/foldername1/**/*_spec.rb, spec/foldername2/**/*_spec.rb"`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Exclusion filters](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-3/docs/filtering/exclusion-filters) in Rspec Project, might help.

You also can run only tests that you want with [Inclusion filters](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-3/docs/filtering/inclusion-filters).

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is for RSpec, however, I was trying to figure out how to do this with minitest and the --exclude flag only filters on name, not file location.

To do this with file location in minitest you need to add a rake task.

lib/tasks/test.rake

```
# lib/tasks/test.rake

Rake::Task["test:system"].clear

namespace :test do
  desc "Run all system tests except test/serial folder"
  task system: "test:prepare" do
    $: << "test"
    test_files = FileList["test/system/**/*_test.rb"].exclude(
      "test/system/serial/**/*_test.rb"
    )
    Rails::TestUnit::Runner.run(test_files)
  end

  desc "Run all serial test folder"
  task serial: "test:prepare" do
    $: << "test"
    test_files = FileList["test/system/serial/*_test.rb"]
    Rails::TestUnit::Runner.run(test_files)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to exclude scaffolded tests which hadn't yet been implemented and passing the `--exclud-pattern` flag each time I ran them was cumbersome (as were some of the other solutions). So, what I ended up doing was:

**rails_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.filter_run_excluding type: :skip
end
```

and then changing the `type:` in each test I wanted to skip to `:skip`. E.g.:

**spec/views/page_spec.rb**

```
# NOTE: Change to `type: :view` to include test
RSpec.describe 'pages/new', type: :skip do
  # some scaffolded tests
end
```

This allows me to find/replace all in the whole directory as well as being able to selectively include the tests when I get around to fleshing them out.